# Why this.state is not working in render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
componentDidMount() {
this.fetchApi();
}

fetchApi() {
const pointerToThis = this;
const API_KEY = "";
let API_CALL = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
let stockChartXValuesFunction = [];
let stockChartYValuesFunction = [];

fetch(API_CALL)
    .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
    for (var key in data["Time Series(Daily"]) {
        stockChartXValuesFunction.push(key);
        stockChartYValuesFunction.push(
        data["Time Series(Daily"][key]["1. open"]
        );
    }

    //     handleClick(e) {
    //         this.setState({value:e.target.value}, () => {
    //   console.log(this.state.value); // Updated value here
    // });}
    pointerToThis.setState({
        stockChartXValues: stockChartXValuesFunction,
        stockChartYValues: stockChartYValuesFunction,
    });
  });
```

}

```
render() {
return (
    <div>
    <Plot
        data={[
        {
            x: this.state.stockChartXValues,
            y: this.state.stockChartYValues,
            type: "scatter",
            mode: "lines+markers",
            marker: { color: "red" },
        },
        ]}
        layout={{ width: 720, height: 440, title: "A Fancy Plot" }}
    />
    </div>
);
}
```

}

export default Stock;

**
Why this.state is not working in render()?**
*Is it because of ES6*
I am new to ReactJs.I tried a small snippet with React.But this.state is not working in ES6 ReactJs.Help me what I am missing!!

Comment: Please add the error you are seeing, or the problem. Currently, your question doesnt describe what currently happens that you are not expecting.

Comment: plz Answer as soon as posible

Comment: it is supposed to show a plot but does not show anything

Comment: there is no "error" if I log it, it returns an empty array

Comment: Adding console logging in render on `this.state` and add the results back into your question. Is it populated? Additionally, add logging above the for loop on `data` and report back the output.

Comment: @AdamThomas no its not populated

Comment: And try adding a log of `data` as above -- above the for loop, to ensure the promise actually resolves.

Comment: @AdamThomas it says"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')" right after the loop

Comment: and the data does get logged

Comment: Cool got it, answer coming shortly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `function() {...}` declarations rather than arrow functions `() => {...}`.

`function` declarations rebind `this` to the function. Where as arrow declarations keep the current `this` (which is the component).

To fix, just change to this:

```
fetch(API_CALL)
    .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
    for (var key in data["Time Series(Daily"]) {
        stockChartXValuesFunction.push(key);
        stockChartYValuesFunction.push(
        data["Time Series(Daily"][key]["1. open"]
        );
    }

    //     handleClick(e) {
    //         this.setState({value:e.target.value}, () => {
    //   console.log(this.state.value); // Updated value here
    // });}
    this.setState({
        stockChartXValues: stockChartXValuesFunction,
        stockChartYValues: stockChartYValuesFunction,
    });
  });
```

In your class constructor, you'll also need to bind the fetch method to this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { stockChartXValues: [], stockChartYValues: [], }
    this.fetchApi = this.fetchApi.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: nope, still giving an empty array

Comment: Woops I forgot you also need to bind the method. Updated answer

Comment: i dont really know much about this binding stuff so how do i change this "constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stockChartXValues: [],
      stockChartYValues: [],
    };"

Comment: Edited answer to match

Comment: Sorry but still nothing but an empty array